# C++ Windows alternative to lrint?

Tags: c++, math, math.h

What is the correct alternative to the C99 lrint function in windows?

```
#define lrint(x) (floor(x+(x>0) ? 0.5 : -0.5)) 

/* and if fesetround(0) behavior is required*/

#define lrint(x) ((int)(x))
```

is that correct?

Comment: @Insilico The code he provided originally does work if `fesetround(0)` was called before `lrint`. Now it simply produces 0 if `x>=0`, otherwise -1.

Comment: I misread the documentation - I should have written `fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO)`, not `fesetround(0)`.

Comment: Pro tip: In C++, if your proposed solution starts with `#define`, you're almost surely doing it wrong. Whenever possible, use an inline function instead.

Answer (score 3):

There is no [simple] single definition of `lrint` which performs the behavior defined by the C99 standard. This is due to the fact that the behavior of `lrint` is controlled by separate calls to [`fesetround`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fesetround). Instead, you should use separate rounding functions with guaranteed semantics for the desired behavior of your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
floor(x+(x>0) ? 0.5 : -0.5)
```

will correctly round only positive numbers, but not negative because floor() rounds towards negative infinity, meaning that floor(-7.1)=-8 , and the quoted piece of code doesn't fix that: floor(-7.1-0.5)=-8 still, while correct rounding to the nearest integer must result in -7.
The following piece of code does correct rounding:

```
return int(x + ((x >= 0.0) ? 0.5 : -0.5));
```

Alternatively,

```
return ((x >= 0.0) ? floor(x+0.5) : ceil(x-0.5));
```